# flatMap without object in front in a function kotlin

Tags: kotlin, flatmap

```
fun Mono<Something>.update(): Mono<Something2> {
   return flatMap { mySomething ->
      // some stuff
   }.map()
}
```

How does the above code works?

1. What does `Mono<Something>` means before the name of the function/method?
2. How can it use `flatMap` without any object in front? I thought `flatmap` usage is like `SomeArray.flatMap{}`
3. what does `mySomething` refer to in this case?
4. What's the purpose of doing `flatMap` then chain it with `map`?

Comment: I doubt `-->` is a valid operator in Kotlin.  Can you please check?

Comment: you're right it's typo ->

Comment: **(1)** That's how [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) are declared. **(2)** It's invoking `flatMap` on the `Mono<Something>` instance (i.e. `this`). **(3)** It's the parameter of the [lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions). **(4)** I can't tell from the provided code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Mono` is the type being extended with the definition of an extension function `update`.  See [Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).
2. `flatMap` is being invoked on the `this` receiver available withing the extension function.
3. `mySomething` is the parameter of the lambda that will be bound to the elements provided by `Mono` via its implementation of `Iterable` interface (assuming `flatMap` has the usual semantics).
4. In cases such as `flatMap { it.foo() }.map { it.toString() }`, `map` allows transformations that cannot be pushed into the transformation performed in `flatMap`.